# Error while starting the server by using serverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-datatable, serverpod

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouGJ6.png)Internal server error. Failed to connect to database in future call manager. PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: relation "serverpod_future_call" does not exist

I want to start the server at localhost port 8080 but it shows me this error.

Comment: Please share your code/errors as text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806271/why-is-my-serverpod-server-not-running-as-it-should) question. I think it's the exact same problem you run into.

I think my answer from over there will help you:

> For now, you have to run setup-tables.cmd manually on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the table creation manually in windows
See this video it will greatly describe step by step.

https://youtu.be/BQ6JQbp2Xy0

```
cd .\demoserverpod\demoserverpod_server\ (your server path)
.\setup-tables.cmd
docker compose up --build --detach
dart .\bin\main.dart
```