# Why is my serverpod server not running as it should

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

Working with win11 pro education.

After running my dockor container, docker-compose up --build --detach.

I tried and had the below

```
Kojo Mensah@DESKTOP-RJUJLBG MINGW64 /c/src/flutter projects/serverpod/e_commerce/e_commerce_server        
$ dart bin/main.dart
SERVERPOD version: 1.0.1 mode: development time: 2023-03-21 20:01:14.906344Z
2023-03-21 20:01:17.667254Z Failed to connect to database.
PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: relation "serverpod_runtime_settings" does not exist
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 514:18                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin._query   
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 475:7                      _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.query    
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 543:22                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 820:23                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 746:27                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper._run
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 819:12                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 661:16                 PgPool.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 352:22                 PgPool.run.<fn>.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 451:27                 PgPool._useOrCreate
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 423:14                 PgPool._withConnection.<fn>
package:executor/src/executor_impl.dart 61:19                   _Executor.scheduleTask
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 171:20  DatabaseConnection.find
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 199:18  DatabaseConnection.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 86:12              Database.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 310:13              Serverpod.start.<fn>
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 299:5               Serverpod.start
package:e_commerce_server/server.dart 33:3                      run
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 171:20  DatabaseConnection.find
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 199:18  DatabaseConnection.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 86:12              Database.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 310:13              Serverpod.start.<fn>
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 299:5               Serverpod.start
package:e_commerce_server/server.dart 33:3                      run

2023-03-21 20:01:19.584865Z Internal server error. Failed to load method lookup.
PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: relation "serverpod_method" does not exist
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 514:18                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin._query   
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 475:7                      _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.query    
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 543:22                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 820:23                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 746:27                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper._run
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 819:12                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 661:16                 PgPool.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 352:22                 PgPool.run.<fn>.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 451:27                 PgPool._useOrCreate
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 423:14                 PgPool._withConnection.<fn>
package:executor/src/executor_impl.dart 61:19                   _Executor.scheduleTask
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 171:20  DatabaseConnection.find
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 199:18  DatabaseConnection.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 86:12              Database.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/server/method_lookup.dart 47:26           MethodLookup._attemptLoad
package:serverpod/src/server/method_lookup.dart 30:7            MethodLookup.load
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 325:9               Serverpod.start.<fn>
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 299:5               Serverpod.start
package:e_commerce_server/server.dart 33:3                      run
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 171:20  DatabaseConnection.find
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 199:18  DatabaseConnection.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 86:12              Database.findSingleRow
package:serverpod/src/server/method_lookup.dart 47:26           MethodLookup._attemptLoad
package:serverpod/src/server/method_lookup.dart 30:7            MethodLookup.load
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 325:9               Serverpod.start.<fn>
package:serverpod/src/server/serverpod.dart 299:5               Serverpod.start
package:e_commerce_server/server.dart 33:3                      run

Insights listening on port 8081
Server default listening on port 8080
Webserver listening on port 8082
CPU and memory usage metrics are not supported on this platform.
2023-03-21 20:01:21.310528Z Internal server error. Failed to connect to database in future call manager.
PostgreSQLSeverity.error 42P01: relation "serverpod_future_call" does not exist
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 514:18                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin._query   
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 475:7                      _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.query    
package:postgres/src/connection.dart 543:22                     _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 820:23                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 746:27                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper._run
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 819:12                 _PgExecutionContextWrapper.mappedResultsQuery
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 661:16                 PgPool.mappedResultsQuery.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 352:22                 PgPool.run.<fn>.<fn>
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 451:27                 PgPool._useOrCreate
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 423:14                 PgPool._withConnection.<fn>
package:executor/src/executor_impl.dart 61:19                   _Executor.scheduleTask
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 443:20  DatabaseConnection.deleteAndReturn        
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 166:12             Database.deleteAndReturn
package:serverpod/src/server/future_call_manager.dart 100:18    FutureCallManager._checkQueue
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 351:18                 PgPool.run.<fn>
package:retry/retry.dart 131:16                                 RetryOptions.retry
package:postgres_pool/postgres_pool.dart 349:14                 PgPool.run
package:serverpod/src/database/database_connection.dart 443:20  DatabaseConnection.deleteAndReturn        
package:serverpod/src/database/database.dart 166:12             Database.deleteAndReturn
package:serverpod/src/server/future_call_manager.dart 100:18    FutureCallManager._checkQueue

Local stacktrace:
#0      FutureCallManager._checkQueue (package:serverpod/src/server/future_call_manager.dart:136:36)      
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Expected: SERVERPOD version: 1.x.x, mode: development, time: 2022-09-12 17:22:02.825468Z Insights listening on port 8081 Server default listening on port 8080 Webserver listening on port 8082

The expected message comes followed by some bunch of messages.

Answer (score 2):

For now, you have to run `setup-tables.cmd` manually on Windows.

Comment: Can you please clarify it for me. Why should I?

Comment: Because the postgres database is not initialized automatically on Windows. (Windows is not officially supported yet.) By running setup-tables.cmd, you add all the missing table to the database.

Comment: Can you please help me with it. I am new to it. thanks!

Comment: After starting the database with `docker-compose up --build --detach` and before `dart bin/main.dart`, you just have to run the `setup-tables.cmd`. This should create the tables in the database.

Comment: Output of the provided answer    `PS C:\src\flutter projects\serverpod\e_commerce> setup-tables.cmd  
setup-tables.cmd : The term 'setup-tables.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ setup-tables.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (setup-tables.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

After typing `docker-compose up --build --detach` in the cmd, you just need to type the following command: `.\setup-tables`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps accurately ,projects run successfully.
In windows you should manualy create database tables as in step 2
See this video describe it clearly: https://youtu.be/BQ6JQbp2Xy0

```
cd .\demoserverpod\demoserverpod_server\ (your server path)
.\setup-tables.cmd
docker compose up --build --detach
dart .\bin\main.dart
```

Comment: `PS C:\src\flutter projects\serverpod\e_commerce> setup-tables.cmd  
setup-tables.cmd : The term 'setup-tables.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ setup-tables.cmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (setup-tables.cmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: I think  it is running now but there is nothing inside my tables.pgsql after running serverpod generate. For the provided solution below is the output                                 `PS C:\src\flutter projects\serverpod\e_commerce\e_commerce_server> dart bin/main.dart
SERVERPOD version: 1.0.1 mode: development time: 2023-03-30 17:41:53.122050Z
Insights listening on port 8081
Server default listening on port 8080
Webserver listening on port 8082
CPU and memory usage metrics are not supported on this platform.` @Maximilian

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your server project:

```
.\setup-tables.cmd
```

then

```
docker-compose up --build --detach
dart bin/main.dart
```

Comment: This is what I am getting now   `PS C:\src\flutter projects\serverpod\mypod\mypod_server> .\setup-tables.cmd
Starting docker
[+] Running 3/3
 - Network mypod_server_default       Created                                                                                         1.0s 
 - Container mypod_server-redis-1     Started                                                                                        26.6s 
 - Container mypod_server-postgres-1  Started                                                                                        26.6s 
Waiting for Postgres...`

Comment: `Waiting for Postgres...
Postgres is ready
failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
failed to get console mode for stdin: The handle is invalid.
ERROR:  relation "serverpod_auth_key" already exists
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "serverpod_auth_key" are not allowed
ERROR:  relation "serverpod_auth_key_userid_idx" already exists
ERROR:  relation "serverpod_cloud_storage" already exists`

Comment: I have created several projects in case it will work but it did not. I had same error

Comment: Can you re-install docker and serverpod, then try to run the same!

Comment: ok I will but can you help me out if in case there something I had to do right

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in following order:

```
serverpod create mypod
cd mypod/mypod_server
setup-tables.cmd
docker compose down -v
setup-tables.cmd
docker compose up --build --detach
dart bin/main.dart
```